# What was the point of taking The Keymaker to the Winslow Overpass in The Matrix Reloaded?

Tags: the-matrix

I understand that Morpheus and Trinity were going there to use an exit, but where was The Keymaker going to go? He couldn't go back to the real world, could he?

EDITED to add this bit of dialogue to show that they are indeed running to the Winslow Overpass to get an exit.

> Link: Operator.
>
> Morpheus: Get us out of here, Link.
>
> Link: That won't be easy, sir.
>
> Morpheus: I know. We're inside the core network.
>
> Link: Yes sir. **The only exit I got near you is the Winslow Overpass.**
>
> Morpheus: Off the freeway?
>
> Link: Yes, sir.
>
> Morpheus: Fine, we'll make it.

It's clear they change plans once the tyres are shot out, and then again when Neo rescues them. But I still think it's unclear exactly why going specifically to the Winslow Overpass for an exit will help The Keymaker, rather than saying something like 'let's use the confusion of the freeway to allow our getaway from the agents/twins'

Comment: What was the point? ***CAR CHASE WOOOO***

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - It's like he didn't even watch the film...

Comment: I've made a slight edit but I stand by my original post that they're primarily looking to get to a safe house. Presumably all of their safehouses are built around exits.

Comment: this is the most involving Matrix question I have seen on this site.

Comment: oh well. i guess it might not be very interesting to some people and that's cool.

Comment: I love questions like this. They give a real insight into the filmmakers art.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**They aren't running *to*, they're running *from.***

Immediately prior to the Freeway scene, Morpheus and Trinity kidnap/rescue the Keymaker and are making their way out when they're accosted by the ghostly twins. After attempting to evade them for a few minutes their antics attract the attention of the local law enforcement as well as several Agents.

Morpheus takes the decision (after speaking to Link) to go onto the Freeway as their best hope of losing the various baddies who're chasing them and to get to a pre-prepared safehouse with its own exit.

**It's quite reasonable to assume that their ultimate plan was to get *themselves* to the exit, leaving Neo (on his arrival) to deal with the Agents and keep the Keymaker safe**.

After they make good their escape, courtesy of Superneo their ultimate destination isn't to exit the matrix but to rendezvous with their support teams in a safe-house which the script describes as "[Interior : Abandoned Apartment](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Matrix-Reloaded,-The.html)"

Comment: thank you for taking the time to write this. i don't completely agree with it but i believe it is possible that it is the correct one, or that the only other answer is 'there is no answer'. cheers.

Comment: @sumbuddyx - Note the edit.

Comment: @Richard Pre-prepared? Seems a bit recursive. Not intending a computer pun are you? :p

Comment: At least I didn't describe the room as "*previously pre-prepared*"

Comment: How abandoned is it, if they’re all inside it, though?

Answer (score 5):

Given the crew's ability to take elements from The Matrix and recreate them in the [Construct](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Construct) and vice-versa (notably the same battered armchairs and telephone seen in the famous [battery speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGZiLMGdCE0) and the guns that Neo collects from the [storeroom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y70vcs3oV14)) then it's at least possible that their intention was to transfer the Keymaker into the Construct program, allowing them to interact with him at their leisure.

This is precisely what happens in *The Matrix Resurrections*. The crew are able to sustain a programmatical version of Morpheus, uploaded from a version of the Matrix into the computer on their hovership and to then interact with him in their Construct. There's no obvious reason why that technique wouldn't apply to a willing exiled program.

This would explain why they didn't simply make for the nearest door (even though they'd already seen the Keymaker's abilities) and why they were so keen to get to an *exit* rather than merely losing the Agents that were chasing them.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the Keymaker would have exited the Matrix and been saved onto a disc or what not.

Comment: This is actually quite clever. Theoretically, they might have been able to transfer him to the construct; http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Construct